# How to implement IAdaptable correctly?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adapter

Suppose I am implementing `IAdaptable`. For example, I am implementing `IEditorInput`, which requires this.

What to write inside implementation? What is the role of `org.eclipse.core.runtime.adapters` here? I need no assistance of Eclipse API to instantiate Adapter from my own method. So, am I need to use it?

**UPDATE**

It is said in documentation:

```
Editor input must implement the IAdaptable interface; extensions are managed by the platform's adapter manager.
```

I can't catch what it means. Either I write instantiation code in `IAdapterFactory` implementation, or I will write it in `IEditorInput` implementation.

I can't do both.

If I write

```
class MyClass implements IEditorInpit {
   MyClassAdapter adapter = null;

   @Override
   public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {

      if( adapter == MyClassAdapter.class ) {
         if( adapter == null ) {
             adapter = new MyClassAdapter(this, /// instantiation code
         }
         return adapter;
      }

      return null;
   }

}
```

then `org.eclipse.core.runtime.adapters` will be never used.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not extending the public implementation,  org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart, which already handles it?

Comment: I have changed `IEditorPart` for `IEditorInput`. Latter interface has no apparent implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You should extend `org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart` rather than implementing `IEditorPart` from scratch. `EditorPart` and its super class `WorkbenchPart` do a lot of work for you.

You only need to extend the `WorkbenchPart.getAdapter` method to do specific things like a content outline page for the editor, for example;

```
@Override
public Object getAdapter(Class adapter)
{
   if (adapter == IContentOutlinePage.class)
     return yourContentOutlinePage;

   return super.getAdapter(adapter);
}
```

always call `super.getAdapter(adapter)` for classes you don't provide.

The documentation on the APIs that need you to provide something in the `getAdapter` do make this clear.

The default implementation does:

```
return Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(this, adapter);
```

Comment: Suppose I am speaking about `IEditorInput`.

Comment: Added default implementation

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was either in `PlatformObject` implementation, where it is

```
public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
    return AdapterManager.getDefault().getAdapter(this, adapter);
}
```

or in this class doc ([here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/PlatformObject.html)):

```
 public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
     IAdapterManager manager = ...;//lookup the IAdapterManager service         
     return manager.getAdapter(this, adapter);
 }
```